# Unit Testing Spring @Repository & Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing

I'm new to Spring.

In the past when I use hibernate. I can just test my dao easily because it will automatically get sessionFactory.

But when I am using Spring (@Repositry and @Entity) only.

I can't seems to unit test my code because .getHibernateTemplate() keeps return null.

I suspect the hibernateSession is not initialize.

May I know for Spring, how can I unit test against the database?

Comment: Can you update the answer with the spring context xml file which defines the Hibernate Sessions and Datasource? If you are not using xml to configure then update the question with the Config class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any code example i can only speculate. However to test your repositories / entities your unit test class requires spring context to be initalised.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:META-INF/test-context.xml")
public class YourTestClass {
    @Autowired
    <<autowire your repository/sessionFactory>> 

}
```

FYI: test-context.xml assumes you have configured your spring beans via xml and not JavaConfig.